# Запуск процесса из Java возвращает код 137

Tags: java, linux, docker, perl

Я запускаю скрипт Perl из Java примерно таким образом:

```
Process oProcess = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
oProcess.waitFor(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
logger.debug("perl exitValue: {}", oProcess.exitValue());
```

Этот код выполняется каждые 30 минут. И где-то спустя 8-9 часов нормальной работы приложения в логе появляется код 137:

```
perl exitValue: 137
```

После перезапуска контейнера все работает хорошо, но через 8-9 часов повторяется. В инете пишут, что эта ошибка возникает из-за нехватки памяти. Проверяю свободную память - ее много. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: так вам перл возращает ошибку, а не жава. Ищите проблему внутри перл скрипта(скорее всего).

Comment: А что делает perl скрипт, и где хранит ваша ява обертка его выхлоп? можно ли его напрямую кроном запускать? Ява сама по себе хорошо сжирает памяти.